# .NET wrapper for Windows API functionality

Tags: .net, winapi, pinvoke, wrapper, managed

Does anyone know of a .NET managed wrapper around Windows API functionality that is not available in the .NET framework itself?

Areas such as window creation and display styles, common UI control manipulation, keyboard/mouse input, file and disk information, memory mapped files etc

I have been a regular to visitor http://www.pinvoke.net/ and find it a great resource.  However having to directly use DllImport of functions and then locate the required structures and enumerations every time is slow and prone to error.

(I do realize doing things in 100% managed code where possible is almost always the better approach, but there are many things, particularly in Windows Forms where you just can't do it using managed code only.)

Focusing on Windows XP for now, but possibly moving to Windows 7 in the future.

Comment: did u get managed and unmanaged wrong? the terminology? just curious..

Answer (score 10):

A project on SourceForge called [Managed Windows API](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/) looks like it might provide the required functionality.

It appears to not have been updated for a year or so but still looks quite promising.  Some wrapped WinAPI functionality include:

- General Window settings.
- ListView and TreeView controls.
- Sounds and Audio.
- Accessibility.
- Keyboard and Mouse Input.
- Low level system hooks.

Here's the [on-line documentation.](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html)

Comment: Note that its license is LGPL.